# How to calculate the difference between minutes of a series of time intervals

Tags: php, php-carbon

I need to calculate the difference, "for example in minutes", of a series of intervals, however there is no limit, because there may be N time records, between "`tipo_2_pause`" and "`tipo_3_return`".

Excluding "`tipo_1_start`" and "`tipo_4_end`", both "`tipo_2_pause`" and "`tipo_3_return`" is an array with N records.

As an example, I need to calculate the difference between the "tipo_4_end" and the "tipo_1_start".... ok... this is easy... but I'm not able to find a way in which I can calculate always considering the respective pairs between "tipo_2_pause" and "tipo_3_return".

In the example, the first pair between "tipo_2_pause" and "tipo_3_return", I hope to get the difference... which in this case is equal to 10min....in the second pair, by chance, it could also be 10min... but it could be any time .. but if there is no pair, the result would be 0.

**Objective**:

Being able to calculate the difference in minutes between each item in the array "`tipo_2_pause`" that pairs with the array "`tipo_3_return`".

[image]

Comment: Ok, have you heard of datetime class? With Carbon, it should be more simplified. Also, do you need to calculate sum of differences?

Comment: Is the expected output like 20(10 + 10)? It can be done with a simple foreach. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes... I know I could foreach, but I not found a way to guarantee the formation of a "couple" between the arrays item. The way I'm thinking would be to scan using the smallest array. but I'm finding a lot of crapcode the way I was thinking... but I think there must be a simple way to calculate the difference between a series of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the key to getting pairs is to use the length of the shorter array.

Then you just apply a for-loop.

Somewhat verbose (for clarity) first pass:

```php
$numPairs = min(count($tipo2), count($tipo3));
$duration = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$numPairs; $i++){
   $start = $tipo2[$i];
   $end = $tipo3[$i];
   $duration += minutes_between($start, $end); // implementing minutes_between is left as an exercise.
}
```

Comment: Omg... I think that's exactly what I was looking for... I was creating an unending sequence
 of conditionals. I'll just join your algo with what you were doing... It was the `min()` I was completely ignoring... This was my error, as I was trying to size each array and "repeating" the loop... and min() would already give me the size I need to do the loop